# Symbols of animals

Tags: symbols

I'm wondering whether there are symbols implemented in LaTeX to create animals.
For example like the `\Bat` in the marvosym, but for other animals.

I'm especially interested in `\Dolphin` ;-)

Comment: the cow font? http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/ruid=175252896/action=view/id=22

Comment: The [PST-fun package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-fun) can create some animals (octopus, fish, dog, bird, ant, parrot, kangaroo, and pig) but they aren't symbols like the \Bat you mentioned, they're macros.

Comment: We need a copy of the IDL's cat signal because it'd make a lovely operator for concatenation when simple juxtaposition means other things.  http://internetdefenseleague.org/launch

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately, [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) doesn't find anything, and neither does [The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/) that Martin Scharrer [wrapped into a `.sty` file](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1341819#1341819).

However, if you manage to find a suitable symbol (with the right license), you could just define your own command to include it in a document. For example, on her site [mytimetocraft.com](http://mytimetocraft.com), Beth has published a [nice SVG of a dolphin](http://mytimetocraft.com/2009/05/19/dolphin-svg/). The images posted on that site are free for commercial and non-commercial use.

You could either convert that SVG to a PDF file, or you could just extract the path from the file and let TikZ draw it for you. By setting the `scale` factor as a product of the `ex` unit, the symbol will scale with the surrounding text.

```
Look, a \Dolphin!

\Huge Wow! It's so big and blue! \Dolphin[blue,xscale=-1]
```

will yield

[image: dolphin symbol]

Here's the code for the above example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\newcommand{\Dolphin}[1][]{%
    \tikz \fill [scale=1ex/500,yscale=-1,#1] svg "M 240,792 C 236.7964,782.29301 227.32595,769.18429 218.95458,762.8695 C 210.58318,756.55478 193.07658,741.91749 180.05096,730.34232 L 156.36806,709.29648 L 141.17601,721.53827 C 132.82037,728.27131 116.86485,736.20204 105.71929,739.16215 C 94.57372,742.12228 76.825609,750.15889 66.279001,757.02126 C 42.749986,772.33104 35.286663,768.91329 39.793018,744.89235 C 49.786747,691.62137 86.56609,637.47901 123.0161,622.38091 C 133.32885,618.10921 138.97291,610.6592 143.54681,595.28094 C 156.31386,552.35575 185.13223,485.10659 210.50659,439.02657 C 285.62548,302.61033 377.12604,221.91941 502.90248,181.17368 L 545.4538,167.38902 L 523.9559,153.16241 C 512.13201,145.33777 493.01385,137.67119 481.47106,136.12559 C 441.72739,130.80384 454.06939,100.38528 495.97229,100.38528 C 525.1625,100.38528 588.32595,117.28333 612.47161,131.55225 C 631.20187,142.62093 638.05903,143.46536 711.12662,143.70143 C 826.20118,144.07318 875.39668,159.99674 936.18511,216.548 C 957.70508,236.568 977.32088,249.47994 997.76359,257.08148 C 1037.1384,271.7229 1050.5601,280.83354 1050.5601,292.92001 C 1050.5601,304.96929 1043.1872,306.72156 979.27795,309.86153 C 937.41314,311.91844 922.54209,315.36478 870.35529,335.10414 C 837.1142,347.67736 806.21965,359.09969 801.70072,360.48707 C 797.18181,361.87448 788.5903,373.11962 782.60856,385.47631 C 769.33352,412.89887 732.8923,450.74636 708.71893,462.21739 C 687.47223,472.29962 645.39097,477.58347 636.22902,471.31951 C 626.59388,464.73198 633.77941,451.7414 651.00501,444.60631 C 668.76327,437.2506 688.54805,412.99772 693.73219,392.22992 L 697.39133,377.57125 L 659.92998,381.16743 C 639.32621,383.14537 594.48504,391.40641 560.28293,399.5254 C 408.28252,435.60753 289.59011,503.28314 223.04114,591.81285 L 199.83212,622.68772 L 222.77838,652.2359 C 249.05732,686.07569 265.30365,731.48301 265.30365,771.09095 C 265.30365,810.05728 250.10447,822.61677 240,792 M 885.93164,242.20228 C 889.77822,235.9783 875.83562,229.90601 868.33788,234.5399 C 865.37262,236.37259 864.25805,239.99423 865.8612,242.58811 C 869.72788,248.8446 881.97191,248.60916 885.93164,242.20228 z";%
}

\begin{document}
Look, a \Dolphin!

\Huge Wow! It's so big and blue! \Dolphin[blue,xscale=-1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That, or even a font that has this glyph...

Comment: How did you search on Detexify for a dolphin?

Comment: @Konrad: I drew what I thought a dolphin symbol might look like. It worked for the `\Bat` symbol, which I hadn't seen before, but which showed up as the third result to my very crude attempt at sketching the Batman symbol =)

Comment: The links to mytimetocraft.com are now dead.

Answer (score 13):

If you're interested in what symbols you can access through LaTeX commands, you might find the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) to be of some use to you.

But you won't find many animal symbols there. The few that I have managed to glean are not actually dingbats but symbols from the Phaistos Disk, accessible through the package `phaistos`.

Examples from the symbol list I've mentioned (p. 81):

[image: cat]
[image: dove]
[image: tunny]

(The cat symbol is lovely, by the way.) Still, you won't find any dolphins there, I'm sorry to say!

Answer (score 10):

There are dedicated packages to add animals (and other beings) to latex:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\tikz\bear;
\tikz\penguin;
\tikz\marmot;
\tikz\koala;
\tikz\owl;
\tikz\coati;
\tikz\snowman;
\tikz\rhino;
\tikz\moles;
\tikz\sloth;
\tikz\pig;
\tikz\cat;
\tikz\hippo;
\tikz\panda;
\tikz\mouse;
\tikz\duck;

\end{document}
```

[image]

(the code above need the development version of the tikzlings package, which is available from https://github.com/samcarter/tikzlings)

Comment: Teddy bears, of course, but are snowmen sentient??

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sure! Snowmen are very emotional, they regularly have melt downs if they don't like the weather. If they don't like you, they just show you the cold shoulder...

Comment: Touche!!!!!!!!!